How can i reduce the size of my animation exported as fbx?
I need to reduce the size of my animations exported as fbx. With this export presets i get to export my animation with a size of 1.6mb, and if i deselect "force start/end keying" the size is 600kb but it breaks my animation, a few bones are moved or rotated during the animation. Im using mixamo addon for the control rig and I connected it with a rigify face, but i dont think thats the problem, because im exporting only deforming bones


What happens if you change the sampling rate to 2?
